# Map in Firebase onDataChange in Kotlin

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

My code count stars (5 stars) in firebase
and I have problem, if it update in realtime it counting not correct

(Firebase now)

1. = 1
2. = 2
3. = 0
4. = 0
5. = 0

And after change firebase [add 1. +=1]

1. = 3
2. = 4
3. = 0
4. = 0
5. = 0

But if I restart app it change to normal result:

1. = 2
2. = 2
3. = 0
4. = 0
5. = 0

Why MutableMap add map second time with new star ?

```
class FireBaseRealTime {

var listofStarsCounter : ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList<Int>(listOf(0,0,0,0,0))
var mDataBase : DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
var mDeviceLikesRef = mDataBase.child("service").child("devices").child("sam").child("likes")

fun allAverageLike(text: TextView,star1: TextView,star2: TextView,star3: TextView,star4: TextView,star5: TextView) {
    var count : Int = 0
    var sumAllvalue : Int = 0

    mDeviceLikesRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
            dataSnapshot?.children?.forEach { child : DataSnapshot ->

                val objectMap : MutableMap<String, Any>
                objectMap = child.value as MutableMap<String, Any>

                for(entary in objectMap) {
                    if(entary.key.equals("value")) {
                        when(entary.value.toString()){
                            "1" -> listofStarsCounter.set(0, listofStarsCounter.get(0) + 1)
                            "2" -> listofStarsCounter.set(1, listofStarsCounter.get(1) + 1)
                            "3" -> listofStarsCounter.set(2, listofStarsCounter.get(2) + 1)
                            "4" -> listofStarsCounter.set(3, listofStarsCounter.get(3) + 1)
                            "5" -> listofStarsCounter.set(4, listofStarsCounter.get(4) + 1)
                        }
                        count++
                        sumAllvalue += entary.value.toString().toInt()
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                text.text = "%.1f".format(sumAllvalue.toDouble() / count.toDouble())

                star1.text = "%.1f".format((100.0/count.toDouble()) * listofStarsCounter.get(0).toDouble())
                star2.text = "%.1f".format((100.0 / count.toDouble()) * listofStarsCounter.get(1).toDouble())
                star3.text = "%.1f".format((100.0 / count.toDouble()) * listofStarsCounter.get(2).toDouble())
                star4.text = "%.1f".format((100.0 / count.toDouble()) * listofStarsCounter.get(3).toDouble())
                star5.text = "%.1f".format((100.0 / count.toDouble()) * listofStarsCounter.get(4).toDouble())
            } catch (e : ArithmeticException) {

            }
        }
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example, your `ArrayList` initially looks like this:

```
[ 1 , 1 , 0 , 0, 0 ]
```

When you add 1 to the 1-star ratings, the snapshot you get in the listener actually contains the entire updated list, which would be:

```
[ 2 , 1 , 0 , 0, 0 ]
```

The reason you're getting the unexpected result is because you're essentially adding this updated list to your original, which of course results in:

```
[ 3 , 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 ]
```

Restarting the app fixes this, because you start with an all-zero list again, and add the data received in the listener to that.

---

So to fix your problem, you just need to overwrite every value in your list when you get an update instead of adding to the existing value. You can do this by resetting your list to all zeroes before running your loop.

```
val objectMap : MutableMap<String, Any>
objectMap = child.value as MutableMap<String, Any>

listofStarsCounter = arrayListOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

for (entary in objectMap) {
    ...
}
```